# Cannot print lines from rdd after using **persist()**

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, printing, databricks, persist

I am using the following code

```
def process_row(row):
items = row.replace('"', '')
items2 = items.split(' ')
for i in range(len(items2)):
#if we find ‘-’ we will replace it with ‘0’
  if(row[-1]=='-'):
    row[i]='0'
return [items2[0], items2[1], items2[2],items2[3], items2[4], int(items2[5])]

nasa = (
nasa_raw.map(process_row)
 )                     

nasa = nasa.persist()
first10 = nasa.collect()[:10]
for i, line in enumerate(first10):
print(f'Line {i+1:02}:  {line}')
```

over textfile :

> `in24.inetnebr.com [01/Aug/1995:00:00:01] "GET /shuttle/missions/sts-68/news/sts-68-mcc-05.txt" 200 1839 uplherc.upl.com [01/Aug/1995:00:00:07] "GET /" 304 0 uplherc.upl.com [01/Aug/1995:00:00:08] "GET /images/ksclogo-medium.gif" 304 0 uplherc.upl.com [01/Aug/1995:00:00:08] "GET /images/MOSAIC-logosmall.gif" 304 0 uplherc.upl.com [01/Aug/1995:00:00:08] "GET /images/USA-logosmall.gif" 304 0 ix-esc-ca2-07.ix.netcom.com [01/Aug/1995:00:00:09] "GET /images/launch-logo.gif" 200 1713 uplherc.upl.com [01/Aug/1995:00:00:10] "GET /images/WORLD-logosmall.gif" 304 0 slppp6.intermind.net [01/Aug/1995:00:00:10] "GET /history/skylab/skylab.html" 200 1687 piweba4y.prodigy.com [01/Aug/1995:00:00:10] "GET /images/launchmedium.gif" 200 11853 slppp6.intermind.net [01/Aug/1995:00:00:11] "GET /history/skylab/skylab-small.gif" 200 9202`

I am trying to print lines the first 10 elements of the RDD, with each element appearing on a different line of output.

I get error like

> object does not support item assignment'

Any ideas?

Comment: the code looks fine to me (except the `print` line missing the indentation). Can you share your sample data and how you read it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine with sample data you provided (I reformat it as below). I suppose the problem could come from your data itself. Try to break down or limit your dataset?

```
in24.inetnebr.com [01/Aug/1995:00:00:01] "GET /shuttle/missions/sts-68/news/sts-68-mcc-05.txt" 200 1839
uplherc.upl.com [01/Aug/1995:00:00:07] "GET /" 304 0
uplherc.upl.com [01/Aug/1995:00:00:08] "GET /images/ksclogo-medium.gif" 304 0
uplherc.upl.com [01/Aug/1995:00:00:08] "GET /images/MOSAIC-logosmall.gif" 304 0
uplherc.upl.com [01/Aug/1995:00:00:08] "GET /images/USA-logosmall.gif" 304 0
ix-esc-ca2-07.ix.netcom.com [01/Aug/1995:00:00:09] "GET /images/launch-logo.gif" 200 1713
uplherc.upl.com [01/Aug/1995:00:00:10] "GET /images/WORLD-logosmall.gif" 304 0
slppp6.intermind.net [01/Aug/1995:00:00:10] "GET /history/skylab/skylab.html" 200 1687
piweba4y.prodigy.com [01/Aug/1995:00:00:10] "GET /images/launchmedium.gif" 200 11853
slppp6.intermind.net [01/Aug/1995:00:00:11] "GET /history/skylab/skylab-small.gif" 200 9202
```

```py
def process_row(row):
    items = row.replace('"', '')
    items2 = items.split(' ')
    for i in range(len(items2)):
        #if we find ‘-’ we will replace it with ‘0’
        if(row[-1]=='-'):
            row[i]='0'
    return [items2[0], items2[1], items2[2],items2[3], items2[4], int(items2[5])]

nasa_raw = sc.textFile('a.txt')
nasa = (
    nasa_raw.map(process_row)
)                     

nasa = nasa.persist()
first10 = nasa.collect()[:10]
for i, line in enumerate(first10):
    print(f'Line {i+1:02}:  {line}')

# Output
Line 01:  ['in24.inetnebr.com', '[01/Aug/1995:00:00:01]', 'GET', '/shuttle/missions/sts-68/news/sts-68-mcc-05.txt', '200', 1839]
Line 02:  ['uplherc.upl.com', '[01/Aug/1995:00:00:07]', 'GET', '/', '304', 0]
Line 03:  ['uplherc.upl.com', '[01/Aug/1995:00:00:08]', 'GET', '/images/ksclogo-medium.gif', '304', 0]
Line 04:  ['uplherc.upl.com', '[01/Aug/1995:00:00:08]', 'GET', '/images/MOSAIC-logosmall.gif', '304', 0]
Line 05:  ['uplherc.upl.com', '[01/Aug/1995:00:00:08]', 'GET', '/images/USA-logosmall.gif', '304', 0]
Line 06:  ['ix-esc-ca2-07.ix.netcom.com', '[01/Aug/1995:00:00:09]', 'GET', '/images/launch-logo.gif', '200', 1713]
Line 07:  ['uplherc.upl.com', '[01/Aug/1995:00:00:10]', 'GET', '/images/WORLD-logosmall.gif', '304', 0]
Line 08:  ['slppp6.intermind.net', '[01/Aug/1995:00:00:10]', 'GET', '/history/skylab/skylab.html', '200', 1687]
Line 09:  ['piweba4y.prodigy.com', '[01/Aug/1995:00:00:10]', 'GET', '/images/launchmedium.gif', '200', 11853]
Line 10:  ['slppp6.intermind.net', '[01/Aug/1995:00:00:11]', 'GET', '/history/skylab/skylab-small.gif', '200', 9202]
```

Comment: Thank you @pltc. The problem is that after applying function process_row I get a pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD object. I tried to convert it to RDD by using                                
 nasa = sc.parallelize(nasa) but I get error  TypeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object is not iterable